# M2.2 Importing large number of products

Tags: magento2, server-setup, aws

I'm importing a large number of **products(15-20k)** using a custom module importer that uses Magento's `core API`.

I would like to `improve the speed` of the `Product Importer`.

When I scaled up to `64 GB RAM in AWS`, the server was using only `8-10 GB RAM` on average. How do I configure `PHP/MySQL/Opcache` to utilise the memory and CPU available?

So far, I have tested to increase the `PHP memory limit`, `MySql buffer size`. Is there a way to analyse and test different configurations?

**Note:**

> 1. Large imports are one time use.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this advice,

https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts

read the info more than once.

Comment: This may be useful for direct mysql insertion. However, I'm not sure it is an effective way. Eg. if I disable the keys(unique constraint), then a product have a duplicate url and need to work on fixing those issue after the import. We will never be sure how 10k product had impacted the consistency of the data.

Comment: @Siva I would hope your preliminary prep would have eliminated the possibility of violating the unique constraint of your table data.